# Passing Data Between Fragments to Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I need to pass data between from 5 `fragments` to one `Activity`,  those `fragments` send data one after another when i reach 5'th `fragment` then i need to store all 5 `fragments` data how can we do this. any idea is Great.[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Pass data from each fragment to activity, when activity gets all data then process it.
You can pass data using interfaces.

Fragment:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

  public interface onSomeEventListener {
    public void someEvent(String s);
  }

  onSomeEventListener someEventListener;

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
          someEventListener = (onSomeEventListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onSomeEventListener");
        }
  }

  final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, null);

    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        someEventListener.someEvent("Test text to Fragment1");
      }
    });

    return v;
  }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements onSomeEventListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Fragment frag2 = new Fragment2();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment2, frag2);
        ft.commit();
    }

  @Override
  public void someEvent(String s) {
      Fragment frag1 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
      ((TextView)frag1.getView().findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Text from Fragment 2:" + s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Kalyanganov Alexey can you elobarate me how to pass data using interfaces if it is with a simple example appreciated...

Comment: Shure. Google have good examples http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: but if I only have one button which is in the last fragment, how can I do that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953477/pass-data-to-fragment

Answer (score 13):

The following link explains the design for communication between fragments.

[Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity, you can define an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during its onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface methods in order to communicate with the Activity.

Here is an example of Fragment to Activity communication:

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {

OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

...
}
```

Now the fragment can deliver messages to the activity by calling the onArticleSelected() method (or other methods in the interface) using the mCallback instance of the OnHeadlineSelectedListener interface.

For example, the following method in the fragment is called when the user clicks on a list item. The fragment uses the callback interface to deliver the event to the parent activity.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Send the event to the host activity
    mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);
}
```

**Implement the Interface**

In order to receive event callbacks from the fragment, the activity that hosts it must implement the interface defined in the fragment class.

For example, the following activity implements the interface from the above example.

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
...

public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
    // Do something here to display that article
}
}
```

**Deliver a Message to a Fragment**

The host activity can deliver messages to a fragment by capturing the Fragment instance with findFragmentById(), then directly call the fragment's public methods.

For instance, imagine that the activity shown above may contain another fragment that's used to display the item specified by the data returned in the above callback method. In this case, the activity can pass the information received in the callback method to the other fragment that will display the item:

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
...

public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
    // Do something here to display that article

    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

    if (articleFrag != null) {
        // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

        // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
        articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

        // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
        ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I did like this, when i click, iPhone inthat fragment i have some button and edit text then when i submit i am comming to main screen. again when i click rest of the list items i am performing same operations at the end when i click All Info then i need to send iPhone,BlackBerry,Android,Nokia data to different activities. I don't know how to do this.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439941/passing-data-between-fragments-to-activity)

Comment: Can you be more elaborate on the problem you are facing? What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 9):

I tried all the above and it didnt work for me. This is how i made it work.I used interface as means to send data from fragment to activity.

**FragmentToActivity.java**

```
public interface FragmentToActivity {
void communicate(String comm);

}
```

**FragmentOne**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

private FragmentToActivity mCallback;


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mCallback = (FragmentToActivity) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement FragmentToActivity");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, 
false);
sendData("Andrews");

return v;
}
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mCallback = null;
    super.onDetach();
}

public void onRefresh() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fragment : Refresh called.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
private void sendData(String comm)
    {
    mCallback.communicate(comm);

    }

 }


}
```

**Activity One**

```
public class Account extends AppCompatActivity implements 
  FragmentToActivity{

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }

@Override
public void communicate(String s) {


    Log.d("received", s);
      }


}
```

Comment: I have tried many methods none of them is worked. Your method is working. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Got null pointer exception at sendData(). By the way, you are sending data back to that activity that inflated this fragment. Right?

Answer (score 6):

You have to go back information to your fragment's activity. And your Activity dispatch information to its fragments :

```
// In fragment A
((ParentActivity)getActivity()).dispatchInformations("test");

// In ParentActivity
public void dispatchInformations(String mesg){
    fragmentB.sendMessage(mesg);
}
```

This is a basic example

Answer (score 2):

You can use Communicator pattern explained in the above answers.
Also, You can use [RxJava2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava).for better decoupling and efficiency.

**1- Create the bus:**

```
public final class RxBus {

    private static final BehaviorSubject<Object> behaviorSubject
        = BehaviorSubject.create();


    public static BehaviorSubject<Object> getSubject() {
        return behaviorSubject;
    }

}
```

**2- the sender activity or fragment**

```
//the data to be passed
MyData  data =getMyData();
RxBus.getSubject().onNext(data) ;
```

**3-the receiver activity or fragment**

```
private Subscription subscription;

public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    subscription = RxBus.getSubject()
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {

            @Override
            public void onNext(Object o) {
                if (o instanceof MyData) {
                    Log.d("tag", (MyData)o.getData();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        });
}
```

**4-unSubscribe to avoid memory leacks:**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
 if(subscription!=null){
     subscription.unsubscribe();
   }

}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution. Basically it works but it needs some modifications

Answer (score 2):

The Fragment library provides two options for communication:

1. A shared ViewModel
2. The Fragment Result API.

The recommended option depends on the use case. To share persistent data with custom APIs, use a ViewModel. For a one-time result with data that can be placed in a Bundle, use the Fragment Result API.

Please read this https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#java

Answer (score 1):

There's a really simple way to pass data from a Fragment to another Activity that is not its container one.

1) In the Fragment: When you initiate the activity, say onButtonClick, pass the data you want to pass as an extra in your intent, as such:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapsActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("data", dataString);
     startActivity(intent);
```

2) In the receiving Activity: in your onCreate method, create a Bundle to retrieve the information passed, as such:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        receivingString = extras.getString("data");
    } else {
        // handle case
    }
```

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

**from Fragment version 1.3.0**

set a result listener in Activity:

```
currentFragment.setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { requestKey, bundle ->
        // We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported.
        val result = bundle.getString("bundleKey")
        // Do something with the result.
    }
```

then in fragment send result:

```
 setFragmentResult("requestKey", bundleOf("bundleKey" to "data"))
```

more details : [Get results using the Fragment Result API](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to passed data from fragments to the activity. This is how I did it and I found it most appropriate for what I needed it.

I found it best to share and update data using a global `shared ViewModel`

In shared ViewModel, I store and update data using mutable live data and I scope it to the MainActivity. The ViewModel is a singleton and remains in memory until the activity lifecycle ends.

```
class SharedViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val selectedItems: MutableLiveData<List<Product>> =
        MutableLiveData<List<Product>>(listOf())

    fun getItems(): LiveData<List<Product>> {
        return selectedItems
    }

    fun sendSelectedItems(items: MutableList<Product>) {
        selectedItems.postValue(items)
    }
}

MainActivity: AppCompactActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // scope shared view model to MainActivity
    // I can access and update data from here
        val model = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
    }
}

class MyFragment1: Fragment() {
    // I'm able to get and update data in the SharedViewModel in fragment
    // to activity
    private val sharedModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
}
```

In addition, you can add callbacks to the main activity. You can use an interface.

```
interface IAddListener {
    fun sendItems(items: MutableList<Product>?)
}

class MyFragment: Fragment() {
   
   override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        if (context is IAddListener)
            mCallback = context
    }

    private var mCallback: IAddListener? = null
} 

class MainActivity: AppCompactActivity(), IAddToPrintQueueListener {
    
    override fun sendItems(items: MutableList<Product>?) {
        // update something
    }
}
```

Here is the link to the documentation about sharing data [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)