# Passing data from Fragment to Activity?

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

In my application,i have a `Fragment` class for Facebook login.I want to get this inflated layout from class in my `Activity` class so that i can display the facebook data in my SideMenu.How to get the layout in Activity class ?

This is my `onCreate` method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
fa = super.getActivity();
ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_notifications, container, false);
login();
return ll;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439941/passing-data-between-fragments-to-activity

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for showing layout in fragment:-

```
private static View rootView;

@Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout, container,false);

    return rootView;

}
```