# How to initialize a view(EditText) which is not part of a listview layout inside the adapter?

Tags: android, listview

Let me explain the question! 
1) There are 2 fragments in one layout
2) Inside the first fragment, I have a listview layout in which I have declared and initialized four buttons.

```
    Button O1 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.option_one);
    Button O2 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.option_two);
    Button O3 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.option_three);
    Button O4 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.option_four);
```

3) Inside the second fragment, I have a EditText view.

What I am trying to do? 
I want the text written on the buttons to be displayed inside the EditText box whenever user clicks on the any of these buttons.

What is the problem I am facing? 
I can not initialize EditText view inside the adapter since it is not part of the adapter.

Comment: You want to set `EditText` text using clicked `Button` text, right?

Comment: Yess...!! But, editText is in another fragment and listview is inside another fragment.

Comment: You can use an interface for callback, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439941/passing-data-between-fragments-to-activity?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Will go through it and apply it :)