# How I can return data from fragment to activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have trouble to return data from fragment to activity.

I have **Activity A**: is main activity for add product, user when click the text view (selectCategory) this activity show to user **activity B** which content **fragment Bb**(all type of Category), when user clicks in some of this categories, the app going to show user activity C which has **fragment Cc** (subcategories).

Here my problem: I need when the user clicks in some of this subcategory which content in **fragment Cc** to return data to **activity A** then show to the user.

A call --> B

```
categoryTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i= new Intent(A.this,B.class);
    i.putExtra("fragmenttype","CategoryFragment");
    startActivityForResult(i,10);
  }
}); 

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == 10) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      titleProduct.setText(data.getStringExtra("nodecategory"));
    }
  }
}
```

return data from **Cc fragment** to **A** but nothing happened (I need from code to go to **activity A** to catch data in `onActivityResult`):

```
@Override
public void onClick(TreeNode node, Object value) {
  Intent i = new Intent();
  i.putExtra("nodecategory","hi");
  getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
  getActivity().finish();
}
```

Comment: Something like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439941/passing-data-between-fragments-to-activity or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity

Comment: it's different my friend in the first one he tries to move data from fragment to activity directly it's easy, in my question I have multi-layer (fragment and activity between main Activity A  and last fragment  Cc ), and when I try to return data activity A not call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to rely heavily on [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/) on handling some case like yours. Using **EventBus** makes our life simpler. We don't need to clutter our code with interface here and there.

A ---> B

First, A will launch B with:

```
Intent i= new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("fragmenttype","CategoryFragment");
startActivity((i); // No need using startActivityForResult, 
                   // instead receive it from Event generated by B.class.
```

Then in B, send Event whenever there is something that A need to catch:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyEvent("passed_data"));
// You can finish B activity if its job finished.
finish();
```

With **MyEvent** class like:

```
public class MyEvent {
  private String data;

  public MyEvent(String data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
  public String getData() {
    return data;
  }
}
```

In A, receive the **Event**:

```
@Subscribe
public void onEventMessage(MyEvent event) {
  // process event here
  mTextView.setText(event.getData);
}
```

For C --> A

Consider that we have show C activity. Whenever we want to inform A that something need to do based on C activities (something we do), we just need to fire Event with the data:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new DataFromCEvent("your_c_data"));
```

with **DataFromCEvent** like:

```
public class DataFromCEvent {
  private String data;

  public DataFromCEvent(String data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
  public String getData() {
    return data;
  }
}
```

In A, you can receive it by adding:

```
@Subscribe
public void onEventMessage(DataFromCEvent event) {
  // process event here
  mTextView.setText(event.getData);
}
```

This also works with fragment. We only need to fire an Event for some changes that we need in other activities.

Comment: Thank for answer me, that what i need.

Answer (score 0):

use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT on your activity B.

Ex-> ActivityA -> ActivityB -> ActivityC - > ActivityA

ActivityA:

```
Intent intentB = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intentB, requestCode);
```

ActivityB: activity B will forward to

```
Intent intentC = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
intentC.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
startActivity(intentC);
finish();
```

ActivityC:

```
setResult(resultCode);
finish();
```