# Passing `SharedPreferences` data from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android

I have stored data with `SharedPreferences` from a `Fragment`. Now I want to pass that data from the `Fragment` to a `RecyclerView` in the main `Activity`.

How do I pass data from my `Fragment` back to my main `Activity`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have stored data in shared preference from fragment use interface to refresh data of activty.

ref.: [Passing Data Between Fragments to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439941/passing-data-between-fragments-to-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have stored the data that you want to send to the Main Activity,
You can load it in the Main Activity using:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
```