# Android send value from Fragment to an activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

Hello guys I have Fragment activity which shows Google map and I want to send latitude and longitude values to one of my activities. But how can I do this except putExtra. I can't use putExtra because I can't startActivity after data are complete. I have BottomNavigation activity which shows map fragment and also Settings activity in another fragment too. And I want to collect data from Map fragment and use it in this second fragment. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data Between Fragments to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439941/passing-data-between-fragments-to-activity)

Comment: Reis questiona nas been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21044305/4305317

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Shared Preference** to do that.

**Example:**

Put value inside Shared Preference in your **fragment activity**.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putDouble("latitude", latitude);
editor.putDouble("longitude", longitude);
editor.apply();
```

get value from Shared Preference in your **second activity**.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
double latitude = sharedPref.getDouble("latitude");
double longitude = sharedPref.getDouble("longitude");
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: How can this solve my problem, please? I don't want to set values in my second activity. I want to send values from Map fragment activity to my second activity.

Comment: Thanks, I also had this idea but do you think it is a good solution for let's say 20 latitudes and longitudes? Thanks.

Comment: Y don't you make a Singleton to archive this?

Comment: I download data(latitude and longitude) from Firebase database and then send it to another activity when needed

Comment: Yeah you can store it temporarily in Singleton object and use it in another activity

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    private MyActivity myActivity = null;

    public void setActivity(MyActivity myActivity){
        this.myActivity = myActivity;
    }

    //Call this method when you want to pass the values to the activity
    private void passLatLong(String lat, String longt){
        if(myActivity!=null){
            myActivity.setLatLong(lat,longt);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         //MyFragment myFragment = ... Define your fragment instance
         myFragment.setActivity(this);
    }

    public void setLatLong(String lat, String  longt){
         //Fragment will call this method
    }
}
```