# How to pass String from Fragment to Activity

Tags: java, android, string, android-fragments

I'm passing an url as string from Fragment to Activity. But I'm getting an error of could resolve `getArguments()` and it is highlighted in red color

Inside Fragment

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), web.class);
            Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
            args1.putString("url1", "file:///android_asset/em/japan.html");
            startActivity(i);
            ((Activity) getActivity()).overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

and inside activity where I want to receive string, I've used

```
String url1 = getArguments().getString("url1");`
```

But `getArguments()` is highlighted in red color.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just pass an instance of the activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data Between Fragments to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439941/passing-data-between-fragments-to-activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), web.class);
    i.putExtra("url1", "file:///android_asset/em/japan.html");
    startActivity(i);
```

and in your activity use

```
 String url1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("url1");
```

Comment: it removes the error but don't load anything....now activity appears empty.

Comment: Well, did you store that value in some variable and checked it.s value?

Comment: Instead I used this in frgament intent.putExtra("url", "http://saptahik.ekantipur.com/") and on activity I used this String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url"); and It worked for me.Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `callback` for that, see this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

comment below if you need do a sample project for your case :D