# Android : (Parent Activity) Getting the EditText value from (Child Fragment) resulted an NPE

Tags: android

I am stuck with an NPE.

I am trying to access/get the value of an Edittext from a child fragment unfortunately it returns an NPE.

here is the the Child Fragment ***(MoincomeexpFragment)*** :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_moincomeexp, container, false);

appSalary = view.findViewById(R.id.appSalary_edit_text);

return view;
    }
```

and this is for the Parent Activity:

```
String AppSalary;

AppSalary = MoincomeexpFragment.appSalary.getText().toString()
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/48298105/2850044

Comment: You cannot store views as static variables

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your parent activity.

```
EditText appSalary = findViewById(R.id.appSalary_edit_text);
String appSalaryText = appSalary.getText().toString()
```

Answer (score -1):

Create singleton class

public class Currentvalue {

private String name;

```
public static Currentvalue getInstance() {
    return new Currentvalue();
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}

in Fragement-----

Currentvalue .getInstance().setName(appSalary.getText().toString)

in activity-------

Currentvalue currentvalue;

on create()

currentvalue = Currentvalue.getInstance();

String name=currentvalue.getName();

Comment: This is an anti-pattern, and not the proper way to define a singleton. Might as well use SharedPreferences

Comment: how can you say that This is an anti-pattern,and Mr. cricket_007  This doesn't really your answer the question asked plz read once again mr cricket_007  "(Parent Activity) Getting the EditText value from (Child Fragment) resulted an NPE "

Comment: It's not "my question". In general, singletons in Android should be avoided in favor of sqlite, SharedPreferences, and other native persistence features