# How to pass data from the interface to activity

Tags: android-studio, if-statement, conditional-statements

First i want to create an interface activity with an add(+) button like this one here

[image]

And the button takes me to another activity to enter the data and at the same time i want to delete the the add (+) button in the interface activity and shows the data i enter in the other activity like this one here

[image]

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Welcome, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question, this will help us to help you :). try to share some code of what you tried so far and be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar example of Data transfer between fragment to activity using interface.
[Passing data using interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439941/passing-data-between-fragments-to-activity) . You can take reference from this example.